# How to connect to a Linux server using vncviewer?

Tags: linux, vnc

I have access to a remote Linux server, and I would like to connect to it via vncviewer (RealVNC on windows). What sort of settings I should look for on the Linux server and how to use them in the vncviewer client to be able to connect?

I know for a fact that a vnc-server is already setup on the linux server because my colleague can connect to it.

Comment: What have you *tried*?  Run the vnc client.  Put in an IP address.  What happens??

Answer (score 0):

important is

1. Used Software
2. Authentication method configured
3. Based on the authentication method you need to know how to add/list/delete users and passwords
4. IPAdress and Port / Hostname
5. Maybe you find something in the /etc directory where the config files are.